# How to make a editable jquery function

Tags: javascript, jquery, function, fancybox

I don't know if the title is correct, because I don't know what the thing I'm searching after is called.

What I'm searching after is a sort of tutorial on how to make a dynamic function like fancybox, facebook etc have done.

Example:

I include a js file and under it I'm inserting this code:

```
$("#single_1").fancybox({
      helpers: {
          title : {
              type : 'float'
          }
      }
  });
```

That means, that I can customize the function from the html file, so it's flexible.
Hope someone have an idea what I'm looking after :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It sounds to me like you're looking to create your own jQuery plugin. If you want to do that, there are a ton of tutorials, starting with [jQuery's own site](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Authoring).

Comment: here another good one http://blog.jeremymartin.name/2008/02/building-your-first-jquery-plugin-that.html